# What is the difference between grpc-gateway vs Twirp RPC

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go, grpc-gateway, twirp

We already have the [Twrip-RPC](https://blog.twitch.tv/en/2018/01/16/twirp-a-sweet-new-rpc-framework-for-go-5f2febbf35f/) which provides rpc and rest endpoints . then why we need the
[grpc-Gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) . What advantages it's providing compared to twirp. Is it like we can provide custom endpoints with grpc gateway is that the only difference. what grpc-gateway which Twrip-rpc can't do?

Answer (score 3):

Twirp and gRPC gateway are similar. They both build API services out of a protobuf file definition.

Main differences:

- gRPC only uses protobuf over HTTP2, which means browsers can't easily talk directly to gRPC-based services.
- Twirp works over Protobuf and JSON, over HTTP 1.1 and HTTP2, so any client can easily communicate.
- gRPC is a full framework with many features. Very powerful stuff.
- Twirp is tiny and small. Only has a few basic features but it is a lot easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Twirp supports JSON-encoded requests and responses in addition to the binary Protobuf-codec while it still behaves as an RPC. You can use HTTP `POST` on an endpoint like `/twirp/MyService/SayHello` with a JSON payload and receive a JSON response. Very similar to standard gRPC except optionally JSON.

For gRPC Gateway it's a little different. Here you can configure any HTTP REST endpoint on existing gRPC service. For example, `MySevice.SayHello` can map to `GET /hello`. This makes it very easy to implement a complete REST service on top of your gRPC definitions.

Hope this clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

To generate the RPC scaffold using the RPC framework for Go RPCs, we can consider gRPC from the beginning or look towards a more simple Twitch RPC, i.e. [Twirp](https://github.com/twitchtv/twirp).

Common reasons for choosing Twirp over gRPC are as follows:

- Twirp comes with HTTP 1.1 support.
- Twirp supports JSON transport out of the gate.
- gRPC re-implements HTTP/2 outside of net/http.

And reasons for gRPC over Twirp are:

- gRPC supports streaming.
- gRPC makes wire compatibility promises.
- More functionality on the networking level.